# selenium dropdown obscured python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a dropdown that seems to be a react-dropdown, and i cant, by any way, click in one of the options. I get multiple errors and the main ones are "something obscures it" or "cannot be scrolled into view" . I've had this error before and i know multiple fixes to it, but none seems to work right now.

I have tried:

```
r.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selecao)

r.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", selecao)

 ActionChains(r.browser)\
    .scroll_by_amount(500, wrapper)\
    .perform()
```

and many many other ways.

[image: photo of the dropdown]

Comment: How is `selecao` defined? What error do you see? Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: selecao is a browser.find_elements(....)[3] (the fourth option on the image). The html is

<div wrapper>
    <div option1>
    <div option2>
    <div option4>
    <div option3>
<div wrapper>